# Eclipse visual editor giving error when trying to run a java UI bean

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, visual-editor

I was able to successfully create and run a UI Java class by using the eclipse visual editor. After few days when I opened eclipse and tried running the same class by doing this -> Run > Run as > Java Bean, eclipse errors out with the following message-

"iwav0120e Launch failed no java bean found"

It does not show the visual editor for that particular UI class. How do I make it consider the class as a Java Visual Class?

Thanks,
-Keshav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution to solve this error was copy the code, create a NEW visual class and paste the copied code in it. Visual editor starts to work after this. Then I rename the new class back to its original name (after deleting the earlier file of course).

Answer (score 1):

Use "run as Java application" and make sure a main method exists.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```